# How does the implementation for Enumerator work in the Linked List class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core

In the .NET resource reference, there's a page on the [LinkedList](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,df5a6c7b6b60da4f) and [LinkedListNode](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,08181ebdd4cdf907) classes and in it, there's a struct called [Enumerator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,674b2c2e532e0349) which implements the `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerator` interfaces.

I decided to re-use pretty much all of the code for my own `ForkableLinkedList<T>` and `ForkableLinkedListNode<T>` classes, I get an error for the implementation of `ForkableLinkedList<T>.GetEnumerator()`:

> cannot convert from 'CustomLinkedList.Models.ForkableLinkedList' to 'CustomLinkedList.Models.ForkableLinkedList'.

Here's what my linked list looks like (I added a comment on the line where I get an error):

```cs
public class ForkableLinkedList<T> : ICollection<T>, System.Collections.ICollection, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
    {
        // This LinkedList is a doubly-Linked circular list.
        internal ForkableLinkedListNode<T> head;
        internal int count;
        internal int version;
        private Object _syncRoot;

        public ForkableLinkedList()
        {
        }

        public ForkableLinkedList(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            if (collection == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
            }

            foreach (T item in collection)
            {
                AddLast(item);
            }
        }

        public int Count => count;

        public ForkableLinkedListNode<T> First => head;

        public ForkableLinkedListNode<T> Last => head == null ? null : head.prev;

        bool ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly => false;

        void ICollection<T>.Add(T value) => AddLast(value);

        public ForkableLinkedListNode<T> AddAfter(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node, T value)
        {
            ValidateNode(node);
            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> result = new ForkableLinkedListNode<T>(node.list, value);
            InternalInsertNodeBefore(node.next, result);
            return result;
        }

        public void AddAfter(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node, ForkableLinkedListNode<T> newNode)
        {
            ValidateNode(node);
            ValidateNewNode(newNode);
            InternalInsertNodeBefore(node.next, newNode);
            newNode.list = this;
        }

        public ForkableLinkedListNode<T> AddBefore(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node, T value)
        {
            ValidateNode(node);
            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> result = new ForkableLinkedListNode<T>(node.list, value);
            InternalInsertNodeBefore(node, result);
            if (node == head)
            {
                head = result;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void AddBefore(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node, ForkableLinkedListNode<T> newNode)
        {
            ValidateNode(node);
            ValidateNewNode(newNode);
            InternalInsertNodeBefore(node, newNode);
            newNode.list = this;
            if (node == head)
            {
                head = newNode;
            }
        }

        public ForkableLinkedListNode<T> AddFirst(T value)
        {
            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> result = new ForkableLinkedListNode<T>(this, value);
            if (head == null)
            {
                InternalInsertNodeToEmptyList(result);
            }
            else
            {
                InternalInsertNodeBefore(head, result);
                head = result;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void AddFirst(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node)
        {
            ValidateNewNode(node);

            if (head == null)
            {
                InternalInsertNodeToEmptyList(node);
            }
            else
            {
                InternalInsertNodeBefore(head, node);
                head = node;
            }
            node.list = this;
        }

        public ForkableLinkedListNode<T> AddLast(T value)
        {
            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> result = new ForkableLinkedListNode<T>(this, value);
            if (head == null)
            {
                InternalInsertNodeToEmptyList(result);
            }
            else
            {
                InternalInsertNodeBefore(head, result);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void AddLast(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node)
        {
            ValidateNewNode(node);

            if (head == null)
            {
                InternalInsertNodeToEmptyList(node);
            }
            else
            {
                InternalInsertNodeBefore(head, node);
            }
            node.list = this;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                ForkableLinkedListNode<T> temp = current;
                current = current.Next;   // use Next the instead of "next", otherwise it will loop forever
                temp.Invalidate();
            }

            head = null;
            count = 0;
            version++;
        }

        public bool Contains(T value)
        {
            return Find(value) != null;
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int index)
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
            }

            if (index < 0 || index > array.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            }

            if (array.Length - index < Count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("index");
            }

            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node = head;
            if (node != null)
            {
                do
                {
                    array[index++] = node.item;
                    node = node.next;
                } while (node != head);
            }
        }

        public ForkableLinkedListNode<T> Find(T value)
        {
            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node = head;
            EqualityComparer<T> c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
            if (node != null)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        if (c.Equals(node.item, value))
                        {
                            return node;
                        }
                        node = node.next;
                    } while (node != head);
                }
                else
                {
                    do
                    {
                        if (node.item == null)
                        {
                            return node;
                        }
                        node = node.next;
                    } while (node != head);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public ForkableLinkedListNode<T> FindLast(T value)
        {
            if (head == null) return null;

            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> last = head.prev;
            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node = last;
            EqualityComparer<T> c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
            if (node != null)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        if (c.Equals(node.item, value))
                        {
                            return node;
                        }

                        node = node.prev;
                    } while (node != last);
                }
                else
                {
                    do
                    {
                        if (node.item == null)
                        {
                            return node;
                        }
                        node = node.prev;
                    } while (node != last);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator(this); // Here I get the aforementioned error.
        }

        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool Remove(T value)
        {
            ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node = Find(value);
            if (node != null)
            {
                InternalRemoveNode(node);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void Remove(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node)
        {
            ValidateNode(node);
            InternalRemoveNode(node);
        }

        public void RemoveFirst()
        {
            if (head == null) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
            InternalRemoveNode(head);
        }

        public void RemoveLast()
        {
            if (head == null) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
            InternalRemoveNode(head.prev);
        }

        private void InternalInsertNodeBefore(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node, ForkableLinkedListNode<T> newNode)
        {
            newNode.next = node;
            newNode.prev = node.prev;
            node.prev.next = newNode;
            node.prev = newNode;
            version++;
            count++;
        }

        private void InternalInsertNodeToEmptyList(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> newNode)
        {
            Debug.Assert(head == null && count == 0, "LinkedList must be empty when this method is called!");
            newNode.next = newNode;
            newNode.prev = newNode;
            head = newNode;
            version++;
            count++;
        }

        internal void InternalRemoveNode(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node)
        {
            Debug.Assert(node.list == this, "Deleting the node from another list!");
            Debug.Assert(head != null, "This method shouldn't be called on empty list!");
            if (node.next == node)
            {
                Debug.Assert(count == 1 && head == node, "this should only be true for a list with only one node");
                head = null;
            }
            else
            {
                node.next.prev = node.prev;
                node.prev.next = node.next;
                if (head == node)
                {
                    head = node.next;
                }
            }
            node.Invalidate();
            count--;
            version++;
        }

        internal void ValidateNewNode(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node)
        {
            if (node == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("node");
            }

            if (node.list != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }


        internal void ValidateNode(ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node)
        {
            if (node == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("node");
            }

            if (node.list != this)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        bool System.Collections.ICollection.IsSynchronized
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        object System.Collections.ICollection.SyncRoot
        {
            get
            {
                if (_syncRoot == null)
                {
                    System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange<Object>(ref _syncRoot, new Object(), null);
                }
                return _syncRoot;
            }
        }

        void System.Collections.ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
            }

            if (array.Rank != 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("array");
            }

            if (array.GetLowerBound(0) != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("array");
            }

            if (index < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            }

            if (array.Length - index < Count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("index");
            }

            T[] tArray = array as T[];
            if (tArray != null)
            {
                CopyTo(tArray, index);
            }
            else
            {
                //
                // Catch the obvious case assignment will fail.
                // We can found all possible problems by doing the check though.
                // For example, if the element type of the Array is derived from T,
                // we can't figure out if we can successfully copy the element beforehand.
                //
                Type targetType = array.GetType().GetElementType();
                Type sourceType = typeof(T);
                if (!(targetType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceType) || sourceType.IsAssignableFrom(targetType)))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("array");
                }

                object[] objects = array as object[];
                if (objects == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("array");
                }
                ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node = head;
                try
                {
                    if (node != null)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            objects[index++] = node.item;
                            node = node.next;
                        } while (node != head);
                    }
                }
                catch (ArrayTypeMismatchException)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("array");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's the code for Enumerator, which I copied verbatim and then removed the serialization stuff that I didn't need. Here, it doesn't seem to recognize `T` as a generic type because I don't use `Enumerator<T>`. So why does it work in the .NET reference?

```cs
public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, System.Collections.IEnumerator // Here, T is not recognized as a generic type
    {
        private ForkableLinkedList<T> list;
        private ForkableLinkedListNode<T> node;
        private int version;
        private T current;
        private int index;
        internal Enumerator(ForkableLinkedList<T> list)
        {
            this.list = list;
            version = list.version;
            node = list.head;
            current = default(T);
            index = 0;
        }
        public T Current
        {
            get { return current; }
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (index == 0 || (index == list.Count + 1))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }

                return current;
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (version != list.version)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            if (node == null)
            {
                index = list.Count + 1;
                return false;
            }

            ++index;
            current = node.item;
            node = node.next;
            if (node == list.head)
            {
                node = null;
            }
            return true;
        }

        void System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
        {
            if (version != list.version)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            current = default(T);
            node = list.head;
            index = 0;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

I'm using .NET Core 3.1.301 in Visual Studio Code 1.46.1 on a Windows 10 (x64) machine.

Comment: Do you have your `Enumerator` type defined inside the `LinkedList<T>` like in the source example? If it's not I'd expect this sort of error.

Comment: Which line throws an error? Why do you need your own linked list? Also you can start looking at proper [source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/Generic/LinkedList.cs,df5a6c7b6b60da4f,references) for .NET Core

Comment: Good points guys, I did indeed define them separately which could be it but I might just look at the .NET Core implementation that @PavelAnikhouski has linked. Thanks for that, by the way.

Comment: Yeah, nested classes can use generic type parameters from the outer classes, which is what the `T` you're seeing in your link is doing. If `Enumerator` isn't nested, it doesn't have that generic type parameter to make use of.